I'm trying to show slots for pfkcs11 and I'm using windows but instead I get an error that the library failed to load
I am trying to show slots using softhsm but I get an error.
The code and error is:
softhsm2-util --show-slots
ERROR: Could not load the PKCS#11 library/module: LoadLibraryA failed: 0x0000007E
ERROR: Please check log files for additional information.

I tried looking if my path is correct and it is. I searched for same problems on the internet but I cannot seem to understand the solutions.
